# How to avoid loading external libraries multiple times ? npm package, browserify and script tags

Tags: jquery, dom, npm, package, browserify

I have a single page webapp built with jquery.
It makes use of jquery, another library and a bundle.js that I created with npm and browserify.

Bundle.js also depends on the same libraries.

My architecture is like this:

- on the html page I load some functionalities to allow user make a first interaction with the page - like search for stuff
- when the user click on chosen item, it will execute the whole app "experience" from the bundle's module.

As example, I will need jquery loaded via `<script>` to execute the first part (e.g. `$(document).ready( ... )` ), but jquery is also wrapped inside the bundle.

How to avoid loading same libraries more than once?

---

This is the structure of my app folders:

```
/ index.js (graphic engine imported in myApp/index.js)
/ package.json
/- myApp
   - index.js (my module)
```

This is the structure of the html page:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="mylibrary.js"></script>
..
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
// here needs 
// do stuff and at a certain point call the bundle module
mymodule.main( startMyApp )
}) 
</script>
```

This is the way I require external modules and expose main module in myApp/index.js:

```
var jquery = require('jquery');
module.exports.main = function ( initNode ) {

    var engine = require('../'); // will import index.js at root

}
```

This is the engine, also here I import jquery:

```
var jquery = require("jquery")

module.exports = function (graph, settings) {

  // stuff
}
```

And this is my package with browserify instruction:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Learning npm :) ",
  "main": "index.js", // this is the graphic engine file
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test.js",
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/browserify --s mymodule ./myApp/index.js > ./myApp/bundle.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    // and here again jquery
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#c-config-inside-configshimjs-without-aliases

a plugin of browserify.
I had to modify the package.json as follow, and then can import global scripts from html.

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Yeeeh",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test.js",
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/browserify --s myAppModule ./myApp/index.js > ./myApp/bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "you",
  "dependencies": {
     // my local dep
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.14"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "global:$",
     // libraries from <script> html
  }
}
```